# How to reduceByKey with 3 values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am attempting to loop through an RDD of a text file, and make a tally of each unique word in the file, and then accumulate all of the words that follow each unique word, along with their counts. So far, this is what I have:

```
// connecting to spark driver
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordStats").setMaster("local")
val spark = new SparkContext(conf) //Creates a new SparkContext object

//Loads the specified file into an RDD
val lines = sparkContext.textFile(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + "basketball_words_only.txt")

//Splits the file into individual words
val words = lines.flatMap(line => {

  val wordList = line.split(" ")

  for {i <- 0 until wordList.length - 1}

    yield (wordList(i), wordList(i + 1), 1)

})
```

[image]

If I haven't been clear thus far, what I am trying to do is to accumulate the set of words that follow each word in the file, along with the number of times said words follow their preceding words in the form:

(PrecedingWord, (FollowingWord, numberOfTimesWordFollows))

whose data types are
    (String, (String, Int))

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something along these lines:

```
(for {
  line <- lines
  Array(word1, word2) <- line.split("\\s+").sliding(2)
} yield ((word1, word2), 1))
 .reduceByKey(_ + _)
 .map({ case ((word1, word2), count) => (word1, (word2, count)) })
```

By the way, you probably want to ensure that each "line" of the `lines` `RDD` corresponds to a sentence so you're not counting word pairs across sentence boundaries. Also, if you haven't already you might want to look into a natural language processing library like OpenNLP or CoreNLP for sentence boundary detection, tokenization, etc.